# How to give content link to CEWP programatically in visual studio?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I wanted to add a content editor webpart to SharePoint 2013 Site Programmatically (using Visual Studio 2012). I want to content link(myjs.js - which will have the html content) reference to the content editor webpart. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Content Editor WebPart is in `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages` namespace. Here is a sample code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://aissp2013/sites/Team/"))
{
    SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
    SPFile file = web.GetFile("http://aissp2013/sites/Team/SitePages/a.aspx");
    using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
    {
        ContentEditorWebPart contentEditor = new ContentEditorWebPart();
        contentEditor.ContentLink = "http://aissp2013/sites/Team/Doc1/ExportVersions.js";
        mgr.AddWebPart(contentEditor, "Left Column" , 1);
        mgr.Web.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Add this to the xml file:

```
<ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor">/sites/Team/Doc1/ExportVersions.js</ContentLink>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur reply. I need to use only client side object model. No server side code is allowed in my project.Could you please tell me how to add it. I am referring the below link.http://www.dynamics101.com/2014/06/adding-content-editor-web-part-programmatically-sharepoint/

Comment: @user1519872, see my updated answer.

Comment: @user1519872, you can mark this as an answer, if it helped resolve your issue.